# how to animate canjs templates

Tags: javascript, animation, canjs, canjs-view

Can anyone explain How to animate mustache templates?
I am following the documentation from [canjs animation](https://github.com/canjs/can-animate/blob/master/doc/fade.md)
I have downloaded animate from [here](https://github.com/canjs/can-animate/blob/master/src/lib/can-animate.js). I have added to my app.js file. 
So how can I load that file in application?

I have written this code in my template but it doesn't work.

```
<div>
<ul can-animate-fade-out="fast" can-animate-fade-in="slow">
   <li>Hello</li>
   <li>I am learning</li>
   <li>javascript</li>
</ul>
</div> 

define(['can', 'jquery','animate'], function (can, $, animate) {
  var Animate = can.Control.extend({
    defaults: { }
  }, {
    init: function() {
        console.log('javascript initialised');
    }
  });
  return Animate;
});
```

I am using requirejs for AMD support and trying to load can-animate in my requirejsconfig file. I have stored my can-animate.js in         canjs/amd-dev/can/can-animate/src/lib.

can anyone give me full example of animating DOM elements using it?

Comment: can you please add it as a JSfiddle?

Comment: @Sumodhkrishna: added my code.

Comment: looks like lacking -animation- in your tag. try this: <ul can-animation-fade-out="fast" can-animation-fade-in="slow">

Comment: @FionnaChan: thanx but its not working

Answer (score 0):

You should use:

```
can-animate-fade-in="fast".
```

See [the demo page](https://github.com/canjs/can-animate/blob/master/src/demo.html).

Comment: can you create an example with requirejs in canjs controller?  so that I can get it clearly.

Answer (score 0):

In CanJS 4.0, here's how you might do it (using jQuery as an animation library, you can pick any other):

```
stache.registerHelper("fadeIn", function(){
  return function(element){
    $(element).fadeIn();
  }
})
```

Then in your template:

```
<div on:click="fadeIn()">
```